# c++ foreach loop with pointers instead of references

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

I have this `Container` class with begin() and end() functions for use with c++11 foreach loops:

```
class Element
{
    //content doesn't matter
};

class Container
{
    Element* elements;
    int size;

    /* constructor, destructor, operators, methods, etc.. */

    Element* begin() { return elements; };
    Element* end()   { return elements + size; };
};
```

This is now a valid c++11 foreach loop:

```
Container container;
for (Element& e : container)
{
    //do something
}
```

But now consider this foreach loop:

```
Container container;
for (Element* e : container)
{
    //do something
}
```

Is it possible to have a foreach loop with `Element*` instead of `Element&` like this?
This would also have the great advantage of preventing one from typing `for (Element e : container)` which would copy the element each time.

In that case `begin()` and `end()` would have to return `Element**` as far as I know.

But `sizeof(Element)` is not guaranteed to be `sizeof(Element*)` and in most cases they don't match. Incrementing a pointer increments by the base type size which is `sizeof(Element)` for incrementing `Element*` and `sizeof(Element*)` for incrementing `Element**`.

So the prefix `operator++()` will offset the pointer by a false value and things get crappy. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Oh you're right. I mistyped that in my question, wait a moment please. **EDITED**

Comment: The first loop is much nicer because you don't have to wonder about `e` possibly being a `nullptr`.

Comment: It's possible, but a really terrible idea. All other developers looking at a loop will be utterly confused. If you want to iterate over a set of pointers, make it a regular loop.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why "This would also have the great advantage of preventing one from typing for (Element e : container)"? I genuinely can't see why that would be.

Comment: that way the Element would be copied instead of passed by pointer or reference, which is much slower and also you cannot change the original element.

Comment: @R2-Dequeue: `Element&` to `Element` is an easy typo to make, and may create subtle bugs you don't spot. `Element*` to `Element` is an equally easy typo to make, but there's no implicit "conversion" so the compiler would immediately complain.

Comment: @stefan: Or if this is something you want to do often, make a container adaptor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks! I wasn't as clear as I could've been, but the conversion issue is what I hadn't thought of.

Comment: *"which is much slower"* - doubtful, especially the "much" part. If `Element` should not be copied in general for correctness reasons (rather than performance reasons), then you can always make it non-copyable.

Comment: Even though I wouldn't ever recommend doing so (because it is an extremly weird thing to do, as stated above), here's how you _can_ do it. Please don't. http://ideone.com/dSokmc

Comment: Is there any reason that you dont want to use vector<Element*> elements? It would give you a lot things already implemented and would avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with [LRiO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32231781/2069064) that what you have right now is probably the best solution. It additionally lines up with how the standard containers operate, and taking the path of least surprise for your users is always the best path to take (barring *compelling* reasons to diverge).

That said, you can certainly get the behavior you want:

```
class Container
{
    // ...

    struct iterator {
        Element* e;

        // this is the important one
        Element* operator*() { return e; }

        // the rest are just boilerplate
        iterator& operator++() { ++e; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) {
            iterator tmp{e};
            ++*this;
            return tmp;
        }

        bool operator==(iterator rhs) const { return e == rhs.e; }
        bool operator!=(iterator rhs) const { return e != rhs.e; }
    };

    iterator begin() { return {elements}; };
    iterator end()   { return {elements + size}; };
};
```

You could consider inheriting from [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) to get the typedefs right, or using [`boost::iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html). But this'll at least give you the functionality.

Comment: A slightly more generic version of your `iterator` ends up being surprisingly useful -- it lets you iterate over integers without having a backing container, for example.  (Replace `Element*` with `T`, get your typedefs right, and boom, feature-riffic)

Comment: @Barry Thanks! Thats exactly the type of solution I wanted to see here ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can see why you'd want to do this, since an `Element*`→`Element` typo would be caught as an error right away, whereas an `Element&`→`Element` typo is usually a silent bug. However, in the grand scheme of things, I don't think it's worth transforming your entire container.

You could try to create a container adaptor that maintains the current behaviour of its iterators, except in the value type they expose… but I'm not even sure it's possible to do that without breaking various preconditions.

Personally, I just wouldn't.

Comment: Also, where do you draw the line? Users of the class could accidentally write their own function taking an `Element` argument instead of an `Element&` one, creating silent bugs as well. Or what if they accidentally write a loop like `for (int i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i) { Element e = container[i]; /* ... */ }` when they actually wanted an `Element&`? C++ programmers are used to paying attention to the distinction between copies and references, so this whole problem looks like a non-issue to me.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Agreed.